# typing: Define a type that can only be certain strings?

Tags: python, python-3.x, typing

How can I use the *typing* module, to create a type that can be certain strings?

E.g. let's say I need a type `CondOperator`, which can be any of these strings:

```
['=', '>', '<', '>=', '<=', '<>', '!=']
```

I was hoping for `CondOperator = String['=', '>', '<', '>=', '<=', '<>', '!=']`, but there is no `String` in `typing`. So this doesn't work.

How can define such type?

Comment: `typing` is the wrong tool for that. You're trying to check the _value_ of the string, not the _type_. If you want type safety, use an enum.

Comment: Types are just labels donkey Kong ask tierry

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Python 3.8 has introduced the `Literal` type in `typing`. It's also accessible via the `typing_extensions` package in previous versions of Python. With `Literal`, you can define your type as:

```py
from typing import Literal

CondOperator = Literal['=', '>', '<', '>=', '<=', '<>', '!=']
```

The [mypy docs](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/literal_types.html) on `Literal` is a good read.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica Well, you can force `x` to be literal by explicitly marking it as a literal (`x: CondOperator = '>'` or `x: Literal['>'] = '>'`), or marking it as final (`x: Final = '>'`). Either way, it would type check if you feed `x` to a function that accepts `CondOperator`.

Comment: @user2357112 I don’t think that’s correct - the docs clearly show Literal variables and function parameters being typed as such.

Comment: Turns out, `typing` is the right tool for that.