# Python type hinting annotation for Dataclass attribute

Tags: python, python-3.x, annotations, type-hinting, python-dataclasses

I have a `dataclass` and I use it as a constant store.

```
@dataclass
class MyClass:
    CONSTANT_1 = "first"
    CONSTANT_2 = "second"
```

I have a function:

```
def my_func(value: ?):
   print(value)
```

I want to add annotation to my function to specify that possible *value* is one of attribute of **MyClass**

How to do it (I am using python 3.10) ?

Comment: this is not ideal. dataclasses isn't needed for store constants. do you store any instnace vars at all?

Comment: Why it not good? You can use dataclass to store your constants if you want, why not?

Comment: but it's pointless, i mean

Comment: dataclass generates `__init__` and `__repr__` for example. in above case that is basically not used.

Comment: It allow you to separate constant, group it and looks very cool and simple. I do not call it anywhere. it like a container only.

Comment: right, but dataclass is meant to be instantiate. for example like `MyClass()`. but as you said, in above case there's no point to creating an object of type MyClass. Since you can already just do `MyClass.CONSTANT_1` for example, so there's not need for an object specifically - unless i misunderstand the ask of course.

Comment: Question about type hinting. How to add annotation to my function.

Comment: I added an answer below, hopefully it is helpful

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully I not misunderstand the ask, please let me know if so. But I think in this case is best to use [`Enum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html) type in python.

Here is a simple example:

```py
from enum import Enum


class MyEnum(Enum):
    CONSTANT_1 = "first"
    CONSTANT_2 = "second"
```

Then to answer the second part, for annotation the `?` becomes a `MyEnum`. This means any enum member of this type, but not the type (class) itself.

```py
def my_func(value: MyEnum):
    print(value, value.name, value.value)
```

Putting it all together, it becomes like:

```py
from enum import Enum


class MyEnum(Enum):
    CONSTANT_1 = "first"
    CONSTANT_2 = "second"


def my_func(value: MyEnum):
    # technically you can remove this check
    if not isinstance(value, MyEnum):
        return

    print(value, value.name, value.value)

# note below: only type checker or ide complain, but code still runs fine

my_func('hello')            # not OK!
my_func('second')           # not OK!
my_func(MyEnum)             # not OK!
my_func(MyEnum.CONSTANT_1)  # OK
```

Comment: Yes, It a correct answer for Enum, I want to skip .value thats why I do not use Enum for this. But thank you for your answer!

Comment: oh I see. yes the .value is kind of not ideal to type out each time, agreed

Answer (score 0):

I think you're asking an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). From your response in the comments, it seems like what you want is rather:

- Have a class-like interface to hold a bunch of constant values.
- Constraint the argument to only take the above values.

As as mentioned in rv.kvetch's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72394718/4909228), the conventional way of doing this is to use enums. I'm not sure what you mean by "wanting to skip `.value`", the `value` field of an enum simply gives you what's associated with that enum, and I would say that it's not important at all. Here's an example:

```
class StrEnum(enum.Enum):
  FIRST = "first"
  SECOND = "second"

class StrEnum2(enum.Enum):
  FIRST = "first"
  SECOND = "second"

print(StrEnum.FIRST.value)  # first
print(StrEnum2.FIRST.value)  # first
print(StrEnum.FIRST.value == StrEnum2.FIRST.value)  # True
print(StrEnum.FIRST == StrEnum2.FIRST)  # False

class IntEnum(enum.Enum):
  FIRST = enum.auto()
  SECOND = enum.auto()

print(IntEnum.FIRST.value)  # 1
print(IntEnum.SECOND.value)  # 2
```

What I want to show with this example are two things:

1. You don't really need `.value` at all if you're just comparing enums.
2. You don't even need to manually assign values to the enums; you can use `enum.auto()` to auto-assign a unique value to it.

Because at the end of the day, enums themselves already represent a choice among valid choices, so it doesn't matter what values it has.

---

That said, if what you want is just to put a type constraint on what values an argument can type, and not have to use enums, then you can use the `Literal` type. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49841133/typing-define-a-type-that-can-only-be-certain-strings/60860082#60860082) for details. For your example, you could do something like:

```
from typing import Literal, Final

def my_func(value: Literal["first", "second"]):
   print(value)

my_func("first")  # ok
my_func("not first")  # bad
x = "first"
y: Final = "first"
my_func(x)  # bad, because `x` is not final
my_func(y)  # ok
```

But note that type annotations don't really prevent you from calling a function with an invalid value, it's just a hint for IDEs and type checkers.